# Function with 'varargin' giving error when providing name-value pair only: MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function, parsing

I'm trying to build my own version of MATLAB's `dir` function. My current code (below) almost works but I am having trouble parsing a certain combination of inputs.

What I would like it to do is this:

- Don't list hidden folders.
- Have a Boolean parameter (default is false) to return only directory names and not files.
- Have an optional field for the path of the folder (default is current directory).

---

To be clearer, I would like to create the function `dir2` which can handle these combinations:

1. `dir2` *This should list every not-hidden file or folder in the current directory*
2. `dir2('path_to_directory')` *This should list every not-hidden file or folder in the specified directory*
3. `dir2('OnlyDirectories', true)` *This should list only the not-hidden folders in the current directory*
4. `dir2('path_to_directory', 'OnlyDirectories', true)` *This should list only the not-hidden folders in the specified directory*

---

My current version is this:

```
function list = dir2(varargin)
    p = inputParser;

    addOptional(p, 'name', '.', @ischar);
    addParameter(p, 'OnlyDirectories', false, @islogical);
    parse(p, varargin{:});

    list = dir(p.Results.name);
    if p.Results.OnlyDirectories
        dirFlags = [list.isdir];
        list = list(dirFlags); % Keeping only directories
    end
    % Deleting hidden folders from the list
    list = list(arrayfun(@(x) ~strcmp(x.name(1),'.'), list)); 
end
```

This works fine for cases **1**, **2** and **4** but it doesn't work for case **3**. In this case it gives me the error:

> Expected a string scalar or character vector for the parameter name, instead the input type was 'logical'.

I think I might be missing something trivial about MATLAB's input parsing but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that the parser appears to give some odd results, a related question might be [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38961613/inputparser-validation-argument-not-acting-as-expected).

One work-around, which works for your function in its current form, would be to add a check for if 2 inputs are given. If there are 2 inputs, assume it's your `OnlyDirectories` flag and use the default `name` value. The code would look like this and passes all 4 of your example use cases.

```
function list = dir2(varargin)
    p = inputParser;
    addOptional(p, 'name', '.', @ischar);
    addParameter(p, 'OnlyDirectories', false, @islogical);
    if numel(varargin) == 2 
        varargin = [{'.'}, varargin]; 
    end
    parse(p, varargin{:});
    list = dir(p.Results.name);
    if p.Results.OnlyDirectories
        dirFlags = [list.isdir];
        list = list(dirFlags); 
    end
    list = list(arrayfun(@(x) ~strcmp(x.name(1),'.'), list)); 
end
```

---

This *is* a bit hacky though, and has scope to give confusing error messages. It would be better to just have both inputs as name-value pairs

```
function list = dir2(varargin)
    p = inputParser;
    addParameter(p, 'name', '.', @ischar);
    addParameter(p, 'OnlyDirectories', false, @islogical);
    % ... other code
end
```

Use: `dir2('name', 'C:/Folder/MyStuff/', 'OnlyDirectories', true)`

Comment: Rather than assuming something, I suppose you could check it and act correspondingly. For instance 1. check if you have 2 arguments (just like you do now) 2. Check whether the argument is actually what you expected 3. Either handle it, or explicitly throw a relevant error.

Comment: Yep definitely, or loop through all `varargin` members and assign variables based on other criteria. Although as I noted that solution is a bit hacky anyway and further checks is akin to putting more tape on a leaky pipe rather than using a better pipe!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your [validation function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputparser.addoptional.html#inputarg_validationFcn) for your [optional argument](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputparser.addoptional.html) is not specific enough. As you have it, it is only checking that it is a [character array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ischar.html). When you only pass `'OnlyDirectories', true` as the arguments for your third case, the string `'OnlyDirectories'` passes your validation function and is used as the value for parameter `'name'`. You then get an error because the remaining argument is a logical value and not a parameter name string.

Using this as a more stringent validation function works for me:

```
addOptional(p, 'name', '.', @(d) (exist(d, 'dir') == 7));
```

This uses [`exist`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exist.html) to check if the optional argument is a valid folder. For your third case, the string `'OnlyDirectories'` doesn't pass the validation function for your optional parameter `'name'`, thus the default value is used and the string is passed along to check for the next parameter.

**EDIT:**

To clarify, the inherent problem is that you're wanting to include an optional argument that is a *character string*, and parameter-value pairs are always going to begin with a parameter name which is a character string as well. There is some (potentially unavoidable) ambiguity in such a case, and the only way `inputParser` can clearly distinguish an optional character string from the parameter name of a subsequent parameter-value pair is via the validation function you provide. If the difference between them can't be made sufficiently clear, you should instead use [required arguments](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputparser.addrequired.html) or [parameter-value pairs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputparser.addparameter.html). Note that this wouldn't be a problem if your optional argument were anything other than a [character array or string](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/characters-and-strings.html).

However, if you're set on using an optional parameter, the example I provide above for a more-specific validation function is just one approach. There are other options that may be more to your liking. You could instead check that the optional parameter string isn't any of the parameter names for your function:

```
addOptional(p, 'name', '.', @(d) ~ismember(d, {'OnlyDirectories', ...}));
```

This comes with the limitation that you could never search through a folder with the name of one of your input parameters (an ambiguity you may have to accept regardless of the solution you choose).

Still another solution would allow you to use optional arguments like `'path_to_folder/*.csv'` (i.e. wildcard indicators and paths to files):

```
addOptional(p, 'name', '.', @name_check);
...

function isValid = name_check(d)
  try
    [dirPath, fileName, fileExt] = fileparts(d);
    isValid = ismember('*', d) ...  % A wildcard, not allowed in parameter names
              || (isempty(fileExt) && (exist(d, 'dir') == 7)) ...      % A folder path
              || (~isempty(fileExt) && (exist(dirPath, 'dir') == 7));  % A file path
  catch
    isValid = false;  % Any failure of the above indicates an invalid argument
  end
end
```

Comment: I really like this answer, but there is a problem. I know that this wasn't explicitly stated in the question, but this method doesn't allow me to call the function like this: `dir2('path_to_folder/*.csv')` in order to list all `.csv` files in the given path.
Do you think that it would be possible to have a validation function that returns `true` if the given input is also a valid input for `dir`? Or something similar

Comment: In my opinion this is no way to distinguish between the strings in name-value pairs and arguments. This is ambiguous, counter-intuitive and buggy. For example, just for an example, what happens if you have a directory named "OnlyDirectories"? The right solution is the one by @Wolfie.

Comment: @jackscorrow: I added some more options that may be to your liking. However, there may still be some inherent limitations you may run into, which I also added to the discussion.

Comment: @crazyGamer: If an optional string argument is desired instead of a parameter-value pair, then there is really no way around some of the ambiguity, which wouldn't be the case if the optional argument were any other type. This is an inherent issue to the approach the OP is taking. The options I list above minimize the issues as best as I can discern. If that's not sufficient, another approach is needed (i.e. required arguments or parameter-value pairs).

Comment: @gnovice As you said, with the specifics I gave, there are some ambiguities that can't be avoided. I accepted the other answer because in the end, if I want to get rid of those ambiguities that's what I have to do. I appreciated your answer very much though, since you sticked to my specifications and tried to do the best you could. That's why I gave it an upvote.